# FormulaArray Producing Runtime 1004 Error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to run the following procedure that entails placing an array formula in a range ("CA2010") on a sheet ("Slate Data").

I've tested the the array formula many times and it produces the desired results.

The sub below gets

> run-time '1004' error: Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class.

```
Sub countuniqueBINs()

Dim placementoutlook As Workbook
Set placementoutlook = Excel.Workbooks("Placement Outlook")
Dim sdws As Worksheet
Set sdws = placementoutlook.Sheets("Slate Data")

sdws.Range("CA2010").NumberFormat = "general"
sdws.Range("CA2010").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(E2:E2000,ROW(E2:E2000)-ROW(E2),0,1)),MATCH(""~""&E2:E2000,E2:E2000&"""",0)),ROW(E2:E2000)-ROW(E2)+1),1))"

End Sub
```

I tried breaking the array formula into two parts based on some guidance out there, but it still did not resolve the issue.

Comment: "CA2010" is not a valid range name, or is that the actual cell address?  Your formula works fine for me in A1, but not in CA2010 for some reason (though I can enter it manually there...).

Comment: Hmm...CA2010 is a cell address (column CA, Row 2010), someplace way out of the way of my sheet data...but, of course, I tried putting this in E2001 (column E, Row 2001) and now...naturally, after hours of screwing around with this. It works.

Thanks very much for the sanity check on this. We'll see if this is actually repeatable.

Comment: Weird - if anyone here knows why this works in one cell but not another, please chime in...

Comment: I believe it's because that formula is over 255 characters in R1C1 format. If you make the references absolute it should work.

Comment: @Rory - thanks I didn't know that (the R1C1 conversion) was a thing but totally explains the problem.

Comment: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/working-with-range-formulaarray-in-vba/ - see the "Troubleshooting" section

Comment: I can confirm the [workaround](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/) in the linked article for entering long array formula works in this case too.

Comment: @Rory IMHO this Q deserves an answer, and your commnt _is_ the answer.  Could you add one?

Comment: Nice of Colin to cite me in that article ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the `R1C1` format version of your formula exceeds 255 characters (even though the `A1` style version is much shorter than that) due to the relative references. If you use absolute references, the formula is short enough to be entered using `FormulaArray`; if you can't do that, you'll need to use the workaround of splitting the formula into sections so that you can use the `Range.Replace` method after entering a shorter version.